# Code running to slow to pass . Can't figure out why

Tags: java, performance

I have to solve this exercise and I am pretty new to coding. The task is:

In this problem, the input to your program is an array of N characters, each of which is either (, ), [ or ], and your program must return true if the parentheses are properly matched, and false if they are not.

The code works and solves all the tests correct, but it is to slow to pass overall and I can't figure out why. What can I do to improve the speed of the code? Thank in advance.

```
public class Dyck {
public boolean checkParentheses(ArrayList<Character> input) {
    Stack<Character> s = new Stack<>();
    Stack<Character> s2 = new Stack<>();


    for(var c : input){
        s.add(0, c);
    }

    Character c2;
    Character c = s.pop();

    if (c != ')' && c != ']') {
        s2.add(c);
    }
    var size = s.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        c = s.pop();
        if (c == '[' || c == '(') {
            s2.add(c);
        }

        if (c == ')') {
            if (s2.isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }

            c2 = s2.pop();
            if (c2 != '(') {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (c == ']') {
            if (s2.isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }

            c2 = s2.pop();
            if (c2 != '[') {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (s.isEmpty() && s2.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It seems to do a lot of extra work. The underlying requirement is to keep track of `(`/`[` and make sure they're matching and balancing. To do that the only thing that's required is a stack of `(`/`[` and every time you see a `)`/`]` that stack can be popped to make sure there's a matching "open". If you get to the end of input and there's anything on the "opening" stack it's an error.

Comment: It's also not clear why you create a stack of the input characters and essentially iterate over the input in reverse--you already *have* a data structure containing the input characters; just iterate over that.